# Android Studio 2.2 not displaying view properties

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After upgrading my android studio to version 2.2 i'm getting following error when i click on a view in layout designer to see it properties:

> Exception in plugin Android Support Moments Ago.
>
> Missing attribute definition for focusable
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>
> Missing attribute definition for focusable
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertyItem.(NlPropertyItem.java:88)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertyItem.create(NlPropertyItem.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getPropertiesWithReadLock(NlProperties.java:111)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.lambda$getProperties$537(NlProperties.java:64)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getProperties(NlProperties.java:63)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesManager.lambda$setSelectedComponents$228(NlPropertiesManager.java:174)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and Properties panel stuck on loading,

My OS is ubuntu 16.04 and almost i have upgraded everything in Android SDK to the latest version.

Comment: what java version are you using

Comment: I am using openJDK version 1.8.0_91

Comment: Please change it to Oracle as in answer below. O'm pretty sure that this is OpenJDK problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue by changing the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 24 to 23. Actually it is not a proper way to resolve the exception, but i couldn't find any solution at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem with OpenJDK. Please remove it and install Oracle JDK instead using this post: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Then go to `File -> Project Structure` and change Java sdk path.

Hope it will help

Comment: I downloaded the oracle JDK and changed the project structure settings, but it didn't solved the issue.