# Android Studio Internal IDE Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having an internal IDE error in my android studio. The component properties panel never shows anything. And when I click on a component, there's an error in the event log which says:

> IllegalArgumentException: Missing attribute definition for focusable

This is the error details.

```
Missing attribute definition for focusable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing attribute definition for focusable
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertyItem.<init>(NlPropertyItem.java:88)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertyItem.create(NlPropertyItem.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getPropertiesWithReadLock(NlProperties.java:111)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.lambda$getProperties$538(NlProperties.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getProperties(NlProperties.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesManager.lambda$setSelectedComponents$202(NlPropertiesManager.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My AS IDE is updated (version 2.2.2), I'm also using Oracle JDK (jdk1.8.0_112).

Comment: Hi @John see the updated answer, hope it will help you

Comment: @JohnCarloDionson, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40058561/5180017) solution.

Comment: @Shashanth I already tried that, still have the error.

Answer (score 0):

change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 24 to 23, I think it will help you...

It might be the problem with OpenJDK. Please remove it and install Oracle JDK instead using this post: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Then go to File -> Project Structure and change Java SDK path.
Might it will help you. happy coding.

Comment: I already tried that but unfortunately, there's still an error.

Comment: i think the problem is with your oracle JDK, give me a minute i will help you back

Comment: Hi @John see the updated answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: @Ram, read the question carefully, he already using Oracle JDK 1.8.