# Internal IDE error and plugin error on Android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and today I got this error while going for the properties panel in the IDE. Properties panel is stuck and don't load any files and error keeps on popping every time. I have tried these solutions:

1. Clear caches and restart.
2. Changed my JDK from internal to Oracle JDK 1.8 installed in the system.
3. Reinstalled the Android Support Plugin.
4. Reinstalled Android Studio.
5. Deleted .idea files and .iml files from project files.

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in Advance

```
Missing attribute definition for focusable

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing attribute definition for focusable
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertyItem.<init>(NlPropertyItem.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertyItem.create(NlPropertyItem.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getPropertiesWithReadLock(NlProperties.java:123)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.lambda$getProperties$0(NlProperties.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getProperties(NlProperties.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getProperties(NlProperties.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesManager.lambda$setSelectedComponents$1(NlPropertiesManager.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: consider on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050800/android-studio-2-2-not-displaying-view-properties) try to update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

Comment: @anatoli doesn't work for me..............need to get something more accurate and specific